# Implementing a distributed database

Tags: database, database-design, distribution, distributed-system

I need to implement and algorithm for deadlock avoidance and detection in a database system. I would like to know how do i create a distributed database system for the same using either mysql or sqlserver 2008 etc...
Any help regarding the creation of a distributed database system would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From this you can definitely create the distributed environment. This one will depend on your need but [My SQL Cluster](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/) will definitely fit with your need.

Hope this will make you step forward over the distributed system design.

Comment: I would like to implement a deadlock detection algorithm but it seems My SQL Cluster has its own mechanism for doing so. So how and where do i code the algorithm that i want?

Comment: Go through this documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html